# Images will not show in GitHub README.md even after using GitHub Documentation

Tags: python, github, readme, pgzero

I can't find any information on why I am getting these weird errors. I followed GitHub's documentation when trying to implement some screenshots of the pygames I built into the README by using:
Format:

But when I do this the all that shows up in the commit is the code and no picture. I also added separate folder called 'game_images' which houses the screenshots I want to use and even copied the url of these images into the image formatting, but still nothing.

Here is the link to my github:
https://github.com/wisenickel5/Pygamez

The readme will show what I am talking about.

I greatly appreciate anyone who took the time to read through this and is willing to help me out.

Comment: When you copied the URL, are you sure you copied the full URL and not just the file name from your repository. The full URL should look like this: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wisenickel5/Pygamez/master/game_images/GS_ss.JPG" (excluding quotes). Your line for the images in the read me should look something like this: https://imgur.com/a/eQcTwot

Comment: Actually disregard my comment above. After looking at your README.md file, the reason it's not working is because you are using HTML header tags instead of the pound signs. You need to use # for h1 (ex: # Pygamez), ## for h2's (## A collection of games built with Python), etc. After that, your images should work.

Comment: Thank you @DarianBenam this worked perfectly.